# Converting JSON to BSON mongoDB using Python and shell-script

Tags: python, json, mongodb, shell, bson

I am trying to write a script to put bulk data into [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb)
in spite of making thousands of requests.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                 
while read line           
do                                                                                 
   echo "$line" | python <(cat <<HERE                                          
        import sys 
        import json 
        from bson import BSON
        with open("test.bson", "a") as myfile:
        for line in sys.stdin:
        bson_string = BSON.encode(json.load(line.rstrip()))
        myfile.write(bson_string)
        HERE
        )
done < /srv/test.json
#mongorestore  -collection -test.bson
```

And a sample `test.json`:

```
$ cat /srv/test.json                              
{ "foo" : "bar" }                                           
{ "foo" : "bar" }                                                       
{ "foo" : "bar" }
{ "foo" : "bar" }                                                             
{ "foo" : "bar" }
{ "foo" : "bar" }                                                               
{ "foo" : "bar" }
```

The script reads the file `test.json` line by line and convert the [json](/questions/tagged/json) into [bson](/questions/tagged/bson). The output is stored in `test.bson` and uploaded (`mongorestore`) into mongoDB.

But the above code is not working and I get no error, the `bson` file is also empty.

More information about the `bson` library for [python](/questions/tagged/python) can be found [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/bson/#python).

Comment: It's a bit more invoved than just that. There is a bit more structure to a MongoDB database than just transforming documents into a BSON format.

Comment: @BlakesSeven so even if get it to work it wont be fit for mongodb
so any alternative for this

Comment: You should read ["Bulk Operations"](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/bulk.html) instead

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Don't think that what the question was asking. The term used was "Bulk load". But it probably is a "part" of what is being asked. Just trying to point to "better".